# How to Convert a Nested Dictionary to a 3D array

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert a Nested Dictionary to a 3D Array in Python3. I have a function from another post that accomplished converting a Nest Dict to a list, as seen below

```
def Convert_Nest_Dictionary_2_List(Dictionary):
    local_list = []
    for key, value in Dictionary.items():
        local_list.append(key)
        local_list.extend(Convert_Nest_Dictionary_2_List(value))
    return local_list
```

When I utilize this function, I get the error:

```
`'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'items'`
```

I am assuming this is because the corresponding values in my nested dictionary are multidimensional arrays with shapes `(96,144)`, and not single values.

My Nested dictionary is quite large, so I will only display part of it below. Typing the dict `RCP45` returns:

`{'Sim1': {'01': {'2005': array([[ 244.94081116,  244.95672607,...`

With 3 Sims, 12 keys within each sim (for months), and 61 keys for each month (2005-2065 to represent years), and each corresponding value representing global spatial temperature data as a `(96,144)` array (Latitude and Longitude).

I want the resultant array to be the shape `(2196,94,144)`, with 2196 representing `3*12*61 (sims* Months *years)`

How would I modify the function to accomplish this? Or perhaps use a different method all together to attain this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need a base case check (when the recursion gets to your numpy array). Something along the lines of:

```
def Convert_Nest_Dictionary_2_List(Dictionary):
    local_list = []
    if isinstance(Dictionary, numpy.ndarray):
        return np_array_to_whatever_youre_trying_to_get(Dictionary)
    for key, value in Dictionary.items():
        local_list.append(key)
        local_list.extend(Convert_Nest_Dictionary_2_List(value))
    return local_list
```

Although a change in your variable names would probably be appropriate.

Comment: Apologies, When I copied that bit i used the `.items()` function, Simply typing in the dictionary name `RCP45` returns `{'Sim1': {'01': {'2005': array([[ 244.94081116,  244.95672607,...`. I am new to using nested dictionaries, but this is a nest dict if I am not mistaken?

Comment: Yes, that is. Although i am still puzzled by how you've got a 2D array at the leaf of your data structure (numpy.ndarray of shape (96, 144)). I would have thought that made your data 4D not 3D.